# throw my own exception in quartz

Tags: exception, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz to schedule jobs.
Now I want to throw my own exception from the overrided execute method, but it seems I cannot do that.
I don't want to catch this exception, just want to throw it.
Is there any suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can throw a subclass of a `RuntimeException` or checked `JobExecutionException` which has special semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Check the syntax of the execute method of parent class and see what exception it throws.

Then create your own custom exception which extends that exception(which parent class execute throws). Then you will be able to throw your own custom exception from overrided execute method.